# Activities and fragments with the same features

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, android-architecture-components

I have the same UI-related features and implementations that I want to use once in `Activity` and again in `Fragment`. How do I implement the architecture to avoid duplicate code?

Does displaying a `Fragment` in an `Activity` reduce performance?

My goal is to implement an `abstract class` for other classes to use pagination. Child classes are sometimes `Activity` type and sometimes `Fragment` type.

I designed an `interface` that has the following methods. Then I implemented these features in the `abstract Fragment` class:

```
public interface PaginableComponent {

void onRequestList();

void onSuccessLoadList(@NonNull List<Paginable> list);

void onErrorLoadList(String errorMessage);

void onRequestLoadMoreList(int oldTotalCount);

void onSuccessLoadMore(@NonNull List<Paginable> list);

void onTryLoadList();

@NonNull
PaginableAdapter getAdapter();
}
```

This is the `abstract Fragment` class that implements this interface:

```
public abstract class PaginableFragment extends BaseFragment
    implements PaginableComponent, PaginableAdapter.LoadListMoreListener 
{

private final AtomicBoolean mIsFirstLoadedList = new 
AtomicBoolean(false);

private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
private View mStatusLayout;
private ProgressBar mStatusProgressBar;
private TextView mStatusMessageTextView;
private TextView mTryAgainTextView;

public Boolean isHidden = true;

@CallSuper
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    initViews(view);
    getAdapter().setLoadListMoreListener(this);
    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null) {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(UiUtils.getStyleColor(requireContext(), R.attr.colorPrimary));
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this::checkNetAndRequestList);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    isHidden = true;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isHidden = isHidden();
}

@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    isHidden = hidden;
}

private void initViews(View view) {
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    mStatusLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.statusLayout);
    if (mStatusLayout != null) {
        mStatusProgressBar = mStatusLayout.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mStatusMessageTextView = mStatusLayout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        mTryAgainTextView = mStatusLayout.findViewById(R.id.tryAgain);
        mTryAgainTextView.setOnClickListener(v -> onTryLoadList());
    }
}

protected void showStatus(String type) {
    if (mStatusLayout != null) {
        switch (type) {
            case Messages.MSG_LOADING:
                mStatusProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mStatusMessageTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mTryAgainTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case Messages.MSG_NET:
                mStatusMessageTextView.setText(R.string.no_network_connection);
                mStatusProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mStatusMessageTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTryAgainTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case Messages.MSG_ERROR:
                mStatusMessageTextView.setText(R.string.sorry_unexpected_error_occurred);
                mStatusProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mStatusMessageTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTryAgainTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
        }
        mStatusLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

private void hideStatus() {
    if (mStatusLayout != null) {
        mStatusLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@CallSuper
@Override
public void onSuccessLoadList(@NonNull List<Paginable> list) {
    mIsFirstLoadedList.set(true);
    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null) {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
    hideStatus();
    getAdapter().resetList(list);
}

@CallSuper
@Override
public void onErrorLoadList(String errorMessage) {
    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null) {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
    showStatus(Messages.MSG_ERROR);
    getAdapter().setIsLoadingMore(false);
}

@CallSuper
@Override
public void onLoadListMore(int oldTotalCount) {
    getAdapter().showEndMessage(Paginable.TYPE_SHIMMER);
    if (NetReceiver.isNetConnected(requireContext())) {
        onRequestLoadMoreList(oldTotalCount);
    } else {
        showStatus(Messages.MSG_NET);
    }
}

@CallSuper
@Override
public void onSuccessLoadMore(@NonNull List<Paginable> list) {
    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null) {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
    hideStatus();
    getAdapter().hideEndMessages();
    getAdapter().addList(list);
    getAdapter().setIsLoadingMore(false);
}

@CallSuper
@Override
public void onTryLoadList() {
    if (!mIsFirstLoadedList.get()) {
        checkNetAndRequestList();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNetEvent(NetReceiver.NetEvent event) {
    if (event.isConnected()) {
        hideStatus();
        if (!mIsFirstLoadedList.get()) {
            getAdapter().clearAndInitShimmers();
            onRequestList();
        }
        if (getAdapter().isLoadingMore()) {
            onRequestLoadMoreList(getAdapter().getItemCount());
        }
    } else {
        showStatus(Messages.MSG_NET);
    }
}

public void checkNetAndRequestList() {
    if (NetReceiver.isNetConnected(requireContext())) {
        if (!mIsFirstLoadedList.get()) {
            getAdapter().clearAndInitShimmers();
        }
        onRequestList();
    } else {
        if (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null) {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
        showStatus(Messages.MSG_NET);
        if (!mIsFirstLoadedList.get()) {
            getAdapter().clearAndInitNoInternet();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now I want to use the same implementation in the activities.

Comment: I think you should check [the guidelines on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `use once in Activity and again in Fragment` this means you don't need it in the activity really, you only need to use the same fragment twice, right ? `Does displaying a Fragment in an Activity reduce performance?` why would it ? and would it make enough of a difference to change anything ? nope

Answer (score 1):

One way to prevent duplicate code is to use `ViewModel` and `LiveData` in the MVVM architecture.

Comment: But most of my code is related to UI implementation.